# How to implement Case Insensitive Filter Search in ExtJs 4.2.3

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I have made a time full research on this topic, but i found it so tuff to get a solution for this, Kindly help out on this.

```
Ext.define('Ext.ux.grid.FiltersFeature', {
extend: 'Ext.grid.feature.Feature',
alias: 'feature.filters',
uses: [
    'Ext.ux.grid.menu.ListMenu',
    'Ext.ux.grid.menu.RangeMenu',
    'Ext.ux.grid.filter.BooleanFilter',
    'Ext.ux.grid.filter.DateFilter',
    'Ext.ux.grid.filter.DateTimeFilter',
    'Ext.ux.grid.filter.ListFilter',
    'Ext.ux.grid.filter.NumericFilter',
    'Ext.ux.grid.filter.StringFilter',
],
```

I am making use of the above plugin from sencha site. The below is how my grid looks like.

[image]

> From the above grid, i have added filters option to all the columns,
>   When i search for "vl - bank" (in the above example) i am not able to match any thing, it says not records found.
>
> But it matches the text "VL - Bank" (in the above example).

**All i need to find is an easy method to match the string in case insensitive way for the filters**

**When browsing through google. I could see that there are methods used only for other plugins with a keywords "CaseSensitive: false"**

**But "Ext.ux.grid.FiltersFeature" does not have such option.**

I am bit weak in Extjs, Kindly help me out with a solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the problem is in the DB. Be sure that your DB, tables or fields where your are searching are "case insensitive". Modify the DB, table or field structure and set utf8_general_ci (_ci stands for case insensitive)